# How to monitor guest virtual system from KVM host (CPU, MEM, HDD, NET, ...)

Tags: virtualization, monitoring, kvm-virtualization

How can I monitor statistics like cpu, memory, disk or network activity from KVM host of some guest system. It needs to be from command line of the host system. Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can always use virtualisation-agnostic method like [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) or [nagios](http://nagios.org). install agent on the guest and poll it from - for instance - host.